# getKendoChart() is showing as undefiend in javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am forming the kendo char chart in the below way. In javascript getKendoChart is coming as undefined. Could you please check and let me know how to resolve this.

```
var rdChartBy = '@Model.paretoFilters.ReportBy';
    if(rdChartBy == 'Project Submitted')
        $("#rbnprojSub").prop("checked", true);
    if(rdChartBy == 'FA Completed')
        $("#rbnprojComp").prop("checked", true);
    var paretoData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model.paretoChartData));

    var dsParetoData = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: paretoData
    });

    $("#ParetoChart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Pareto Chart Report",
            font: "bold 20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
            color: "brown"
        },

        dataSource: dsParetoData,
        series: [{
            type: "column",           
            categoryField: "Month",
            name : "No.Of Projects",
            field:"No_Of_Projects"
        },{
            type:"line",
            categoryField:"Month",           
            style: "rigid",
            name:"Cumilative%",
            field:"Cumulative"
        }],

        valueAxis: {
            title: {
                text: "No.OfProjects/Cumilative%",
                font: "bold 15px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                color: "brown"
            }
        },
        chartArea: {
            width: 850,
            height: 400
        },
        categoryAxis:{
            title: {
                text: "Month",
                font: "bold 18px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif",
                color: "brown"
            },
            labels: { rotation: -45 },
            width:50
        },

        tooltip: {
            visible: true,
            template: "${series.name} : ${value}"
        }
    });

    function exportChart(e)
    {      
        debugger;

        var chart = $("#ParetoChart").getKendoChart();
        chart.exportImage().done(function (data) {
            kendo.saveAs({
                dataURI: data,
                fileName: "chart.png",
                proxyURL: "@Url.Action("Export_Save", "Chart_Api")"
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
var chart = $("#ParetoChart").getKendoChart();
```

with

```
var chart = $("#ParetoChart").data("kendoChart");
```

Comment: Strange, that exact code should work.  See working sample http://jsbin.com/vigedu/1/edit?html,js,console,output    So when you call var chart = $("#ParetoChart").data("kendoChart");  Does it throw an error onto the console ?  Or is chart just null after that ?

Comment: Hi Robin,Its not throwing any error chart is showing as null.What else could be the reason.

Comment: Hi Robin, This is the data i am getting var paretoData = [{"Month":"June2014","No_Of_Projects":"0","Cumulative":"0"},{"Month":"July2014","No_Of_Projects":"0","Cumulative":"0"},{"Month":"August2014","No_Of_Projects":"0","Cumulative":"0"},{"Month":"September2014","No_Of_Projects":"0","Cumulative":"0"}]; Please try in fiddler and see

Comment: Here is your code, with your data, and it seems to work perfectly.  http://jsbin.com/vigedu/2/edit?html,js,output    Edit your original question, and include your js references you have on the page.

Comment: Hi Robin, I have tried by including JS files on my page but still my chart is coming as undefined.

Comment: Which kendo js files are you including in your application ?  And in what order ?

Comment: The files which u gave in fiddler I have included as it is.

Comment: Hi Robin, What else might be the issue??

Comment: What was that fillder link you have ?

Comment: That jsbin appears to work fine.  Must be something different in your application.

Comment: I have included the same in my project as well. Not sure what might be the issue.

Comment: Hi Robin, Now i am able to export the chart image but i want to save in particular path without asking for save.Could you please help me on this.

Comment: I believe that is just browser behavior.  IE will prompt me to save/cancel, while Chrome will just download it to my Downloads folder.

Comment: Yes i understand but it is not hitting the controller after save the code is stopping after that. Is there any other way i can hit the controller?

Comment: Hi Robin,Please help me on this

Comment: It isn't hitting the proxyURL controller action ?  If you watch fiddler, is it trying to make the call and returning a 404/403 or some other error ?

Comment: Now i am able to hit the controller but the image asks for save after controller code is executed but i want to save the image so that i can include that image in Excel. If possible could you please provide me one sample example? Thanks

Comment: As I commented above, I think that is browser behavior and have no idea how to override that.

Comment: Hi Robin,Could you please help on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334829/kendo-chart-rendering-very-slow

Comment: Hi Robin, Could you please help me on this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35747532/kendo-chart-category-axis-fix-number-of-labels